Accepting the Moderator Agreement doesn't seem to work right away
There's a new version of the Moderator Agreement and I'm trying to accept it. This is the bottom part:

After checking both boxes and clicking Accept, the page reloads and it looks just like before I completed the form. Only after reloading the page, the form is gone. I've reproduced this on a couple of sites, in the latest Safari, Firefox and Chrome on macOS 14.5.

Unrelated question: can normal users see the contents of the updated moderator agreement?

@RandomPerson https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement always lists the current version, and that page is linked from the Help Center article about moderators.

Is there any page which has the older versions of the agreement?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement/versions/1 https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement/versions/2 https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement/versions/3 https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement/versions/4 https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement/versions/5

@pppery All those links work, except version 3.
